# How to realise concatenation in TensorFlow without using 'tf.concat'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am just using TensorFlow to realise a CNN model. In this model I need to concatenate two 4-D tensors: tensor A with shape of [16,128,128,3] and tensor B with shape of [16,128,128,3] (16 is the batch size, 128 is the image block size, 3 is the number of channels). The concatenation result should be a tensor C with shape of [16,128,128,6].

I know that we could use 'tf.concat' function to realise this, however, this function does copy tensor A and tensor B and it uses a large GPU memory.

How could I achieve the concatenation in TensorFlow without using 'tf.concat'?

Thanks in advance!